# Average CPU usage not fully utilized

Tags: windows-server-2008, cpu-usage

We have created a multi-threaded application which process/parse big files (few hundred MB's) simultaneously. Application runs perfectly. But my client is disappointed the way cores of machine being used. He tried to watch the performance monitor and came to us with report. His point is if application is multi-threaded why CPU average utilization is below 25%. According to him, if nothing is running on system and file processing is taking time, CPU utilization should be more than 80-90%. I am not sure what answer or technical outcome will satisfy him. Please suggest.

**EDIT**

I have one multi-threaded application which loads the file from disc. After file is loaded in memory, i click on process button, and it starts parsing the file in memory. Lets assume for now, parsing is done in one thread. While app is parsing the data, my average CPU usage not fully used. What reason I can give to justify why CPU is not completely used. Any kind of report will do or technical documentation will help.

Comment: I don't know the full nature of your program, but there are many factors that play into such a thing. If it's a read/write intensive program, chances are the bottleneck is your disks, not your CPUs. Unless you can speed up your disks drastically, you may never be able to use all of your CPUs.  Of course, you could put some empty loops in your code to make it use more CPU :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: does the client have any *actual* problem with the app, or is he just looking for colorful blinking lights?

Comment: Point is not code or disc access. He expects if parsing of one record takes 1 second on one core. And he has 4 core each one can parse lets say 100 records together. 10000 records should be parsed in 10000 / 4 = 2500 / 100 = 2.5 second. That's 100% utilization. It's complicated. We tried to convince him that windows manage threads itself and it is better than setting affinity explicitly, but he did not agree.

Comment: @Piskvor, he wants app to run more faster. There is no actual probelm. But we need to tell him why av cpu is so low and file processing time is high.

Comment: @hungryMind: Disc access, actually, *is* often the point - unless you are reading your data from memory (and not from disc), the CPUs *will* take some time waiting for data to come from the disc (because that's usually the slowest part of a modern system). I'll try to find a graph I had for that, somewhere.

Comment: Because it takes time to read the information off the disk. I/O is almost certainly the bottleneck, not the processor. Of course, there's not nearly enough information provided in the question to give an answer any more detailed than that. I'm not sure what you're looking for here... Tell your client to look for the blinking HD access light on the front of the computer?

Comment: Does OS reserve some threads for himself? If yes, any rough idea how much?

Comment: Can't find it now, but anyway: disk access is ~100 000 to ~10 000 000 times slower than memory access; if you're processing data that you need to pull from a disk, the CPU will sit idle for hundreds of millions of cycles, waiting for the data to come in. That's your 75% idle time, right there. To fix this, you need to speed up IO (avoid unnecessary disk access, optimize access patterns, get faster disks, set up "performance RAID", etc etc etc). Note that you can't eliminate bottlenecks anyway: even if your disks were as fast as RAM, another part of the system would become another bottleneck.

Comment: This is not a threading problem. If you have large files (as you say, a few hundred megabytes), it's very unlikely that *all* of those files are able to be stored in RAM simultaneously. Windows has to page some of them out to disk, and reading them back in is going to be relatively slow. Certainly it'll be the performance bottleneck in any situation compared to the CPU. There's no reason you should expect the processor to be at more than ~25% utilization; it doesn't have enough data available to be any higher. The CPU is idle while waiting for data to be read in.

Comment: There's no problem to be solved here, other than perhaps optimizing your processing algorithm to process data sequentially and avoid as many page faults as absolutely possible.

Comment: Also, can your code actually run in parallel? E.g. if you have a 4-core CPU, and your code was not written for multiple cores, it will only take up 1 core no matter what you do, which would show up as 75% idle - as the other cores don't have any work to do. See e.g. [this introduction to parallel computing](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/).

Comment: Few things - Windows Paging, Disc Access, Idle time can help me. Thanks, query was bit vague but help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very vague, but here are some general guidelines.

Disk IO is the main bottleneck unless the file processing is really fancy. Loading several files simultaneously will make this even worse, as the head needs to jump around (for non-SSD drives), and data will come into memory even slower. If you load four files at 100 MB each, that would already take around 4 seconds when done serially - and longer when done in parallel. Your program might or might not wait during that time and just don't process data at all.

So if your parallelization is mainly to process several files (one file per worker thread), then you might want to serialize the loading in one thread.

If you can work one file at a time, maybe your processing can be split up to work on different parts of the file, or the processing itself can take advantage of multiple CPUs (largely depends on your application).

If you need to write back data to disk - then this will be part of the game, too.

I think the main point here is minimizing IO delay (and a reasonable splitting of the workload between different CPUs).

Edit:

Of course take RAM into account - if you need to swap out, this will kill your performance instantly.

The best way is of course to go and profile...